# Alternative way/method that is the same as dup2()

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

Is there was any other way to replace the output of execvp() to a file *without* using dup2() to duplicate the stdout fd[] to one of the files opened using open()?

Comment: why are you searching for an "alternative method"? Is `dup2` not enough? You can use `dup()`. Or `fcntl(... F_DUPFD)`. Or `posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2`. You can call the syscall directly.... In what way should the method be "alternative"?

Comment: how will i use dup() to change the fd of stdin?

Comment: `close(0); dup(fd);`